# Converting function into differential version

Tags: functions, differential-equations

I am looking through a journal and I came across a function that I wanted to convert to its differential version using Mathematica.

[image]

Would anyone be able to get the differential version by using mathematica?

Comment: Yes, someone will eventually obtain the differential. For you I suggest first reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator).

Comment: Would you explain why the question is down graded, I understand how it is done by pen and paper, I was purely interested in how to do it in Mathematica!

Comment: Yes, I will. Did you, even for one minute, try to search the Internet for answers ? If you know how to do it using pen'n'paper then you have a fairly good idea about the details. So, you can just search for the appropriate tools and try to solve the problem yourself. I am sorry, I can't see any effort you allegedly put into researching the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is incorrect syntax. You need to use the following

```
eq = Log[P[t]/P[t0]] == α (t - t0) + β Log[Q[t]/Q[t0]] + X[t]
```

Then take derivative with respect to `t`

```
D[eq, t]
```

> ```
> P'[t]/P[t] == α + β Q'[t]/Q[t] + X'[t]
> ```

Comment: why not  α `t I see that the expression comes out as with  α by itself

Comment: @ALEXANDER that's because every other term contains the d/dt operator. You could imagine multiplying both sides with dt and you get the listed result.